# How to use cross validation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I'm trying to make a svm classificator using Matlab and want to use cross validation. But 
`predictor = fitcsvm(features, vect, 'Standardize', true, 'CrossVal', 'on');`
returns `ClassificationPartitionedModel` and function `predict` can not operate with predictor belongs to this class. So, how should I do predictions using `ClassificationPartitionedModel` predictor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`kfoldpredict`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel.kfoldpredict.html) for this purpose. It operates on the `ClassificationPartitionedModel` class. You can retrieve the classification *loss* using the allied [`kfoldloss`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationpartitionedmodel.kfoldloss.html) function.